# how to search Unicode right-to-left language in ul with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, unicode, input

I have one `input` element that I search in it. also I have one list of names that are Unicode right-to-left Language .

I want type in input and search in list and only show result searching `li` and hide another `li` in list.

this in my code (but my jQuery code don't working!!! :( and I understand my code working for english language (left-to-right Unicode language)!!! please guide me about it.)

**jQuery:**

```
var $lis = $('#friend-list li');
$('#searching').on('keyup', function() {
    var regex = new RegExp(this.value, 'i');

    //hide all li elements
    $lis.hide();

    //now filter those li elements which is having the searched text and show them
    $lis.filter(function(){
        return regex.test($(this).find("span:not('.stat')").text());
    }).show();
});
```

[Complete Code](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9WeK/)

Comment: do you mean a "right-to-left" language?

Comment: yes my friend. for example Arabic or another languages that are right to left

Comment: That should have no impact on how to code works. Do you mean that text-entry is performed left-to-right, but the LI tags contain SPAN elements containing right-to-left text? What specifically is not working? How is it manifesting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it,  it may help you

```
var $lis = $('#friend-list li div');
$('#searching').on('keyup', function() {


    //hide all li elements
    $lis.hide();
    for(var i =0; i<$('ul >li').length; i++)
    { var str = $lis.eq(i).text().toLowerCase();
     if(str.indexOf((this.value).toLowerCase()) !== -1){
         $lis.eq(i).show();

     }
    }
   });
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9WeK/3/)**

if you copy and paste any of the listed characters, the matching text is displayed,

Comment: hi julia, i have created a similar plugin, would you like to have a look, please have a look at here http://ravimone.blogspot.in/